# Issue with login on Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, sitecore, sitecore7.5

I am facing an issue when trying to log in on Sitecore (back office) I am redirected on the same login page even if credentials are correct.

While debugging, I could find that when on the login process, the user is redirected to http://hostname/sitecore/shell/Applications/Login/Users/Users.aspx?su=%2Fsitecore%2Fshell%2Fdefault.aspx%3Fsc_lang%3Den

But once it is there the below issue occurs: 
Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated is set to false
Sitecore.Context.User is set to Sitecore/anonymous

However, the user have been registered and ticket have been created successfully. I could verify that by debugging and checking the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation, I found out that the issue was solved by adding below line on the global.asax.cs

```
public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
    {
        string frameworkVersion = this.GetFrameworkVersion();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(frameworkVersion) && frameworkVersion.StartsWith("v4.", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            args.User = SC.Context.User;
        }
    }
```

It set the user to the correct user instead of sitecore\anonymous.